# What is the effect of adding @Transactional to every method down the chain in Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions

Say you start with a service class public method that has `@Transactional`, within it it calls another service class public method that also has `@Transaction` and so on. I want to know:

1. In case I just want 1 transaction for everything and if something fails I want all the changes to rollback, then I can achieve that by just having 1 `@Transactional` at the very first method?
2. Adding `@Transactional` to every service class methods down the calling chain is unnecessary and is bad for performance for the use case above?
3. Any example when you will want to add `@Transactional` to every method down the calling chain to achieve something different?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/declarative/tx-propagation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In case I just want 1 transaction for everything and if something fails I want all the changes to rollback, then I can achieve that by just having 1 @Transactional at the very first method.

Yes. If any method called lower in the stack of the `@Transactional` method throws an unchecked exception, all the operations get rollbacked and no changes are committed in the DB. This assumes the default [`Propagation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) `REQUIRED`.

> Adding @Transactional to every service class methods down the calling chain is unnecessary and is bad for performance for the use case above?

To achieve the thing described a bit above, it is unnecessary, though it really does not add any overhead. For the sake of simplicity, I recommend placing the `@Transactional` annotations on the same layer. Find a consensus among the development team, though it is common to define right in the service layer that is called by the REST controllers. There are also some exceptions, for example, it is common to place `@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)` in the deeper layers where you need to have such a control the nested transaction won't affect the outer one, though it also depends on how the application is layered. You might also want to place the annotation to the lower layers that are invoked by a different part of the application that cannot access the higher layer.

> Any example when you will want to add @Transactional to every method down the calling chain to achieve something different?

I would not annotate necessarily an *every* method, but I would rather consider the use-cases I have described above.

Comment: Yeah ok. But the overhead I am thinking is the extra wrapping the inner methods with Transaction and proxies

Answer (score 0):

It will rollback to what you have run before. You wont need chain in here